# Apply fuzzy matching across a dataframe column and save results in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I have two data frames with each having a different number of rows. Below is a couple rows from each data set

```
df1 =
     Company                                   City         State  ZIP
     FREDDIE LEES AMERICAN GOURMET SAUCE       St. Louis    MO     63101
     CITYARCHRIVER 2015 FOUNDATION             St. Louis    MO     63102
     GLAXOSMITHKLINE CONSUMER HEALTHCARE       St. Louis    MO     63102
     LACKEY SHEET METAL                        St. Louis    MO     63102
```

and

```
df2 = 
     FDA Company                    FDA City    FDA State   FDA ZIP
     LACKEY SHEET METAL             St. Louis   MO          63102
     PRIMUS STERILIZER COMPANY LLC  Great Bend  KS          67530
     HELGET GAS PRODUCTS INC        Omaha       NE          68127
     ORTHOQUEST LLC                 La Vista    NE          68128
```

I joined them side by side using `combined_data = pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)`. My next goal is to compare each string under `df1['Company']` to each string under in `df2['FDA Company']` using several different matching commands from the `fuzzy wuzzy` module and return the value of the best match and its name. I want to store that in a new column. For example if I did the `fuzz.ratio` and `fuzz.token_sort_ratio` on `LACKY SHEET METAL` in `df1['Company']` to `df2['FDA Company']` it would return that the best match was `LACKY SHEET METAL` with a score of `100` and this would then be saved under a new column in `combined data`. It results would look like

```
combined_data =
     Company                                   City         State  ZIP      FDA Company                     FDA City    FDA State   FDA ZIP     fuzzy.token_sort_ratio    match    fuzzy.ratio         match
     FREDDIE LEES AMERICAN GOURMET SAUCE       St. Louis    MO     63101    LACKEY SHEET METAL              St. Louis   MO          63102       LACKEY SHEET METAL        100      LACKEY SHEET METAL  100
     CITYARCHRIVER 2015 FOUNDATION             St. Louis    MO     63102    PRIMUS STERILIZER COMPANY LLC   Great Bend  KS          67530
     GLAXOSMITHKLINE CONSUMER HEALTHCARE       St. Louis    MO     63102    HELGET GAS PRODUCTS INC         Omaha       NE          68127
     LACKEY SHEET METAL                        St. Louis    MO     63102    ORTHOQUEST LLC                  La Vista    NE          68128
```

I tried doing

```
combined_data['name_ratio'] = combined_data.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x['Company'], x['FDA Company']), axis = 1)
```

But got an error because the lengths of the columns are different.

I am stumped. How I can accomplish this?

Comment: why bother to join the tables side by side? You ultimately want to test each name in df1 to each name in df2 and pick the one with the highest score, right? A simple iterrows loop with a df2.name.apply(fuzz.ratio(...)) inside ought to do it.

Comment: @NikhilVJ can you show your approach.   I am not getting  the approach that is the answer to work.  I am getting  TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() with address data.

Comment: @Chris sorry I'm out of tune from the commands now, moved to other projects. General idea: take element X from df1. In df2, do `df2.score = df2.name.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x,X))` . Then, sort df2 by score, take the row with the highest score and that's the assumed match for X so copy it over to df1 in a new column. Iterate to next X value and repeat.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I couldn't tell what you were doing.  This is how I would do it.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
```

Create a series of tuples to compare:

```
compare = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['Company'],
                                      df2['FDA Company']]).to_series()
```

Create a special function to calculate fuzzy metrics and return a series.

```
def metrics(tup):
    return pd.Series([fuzz.ratio(*tup),
                      fuzz.token_sort_ratio(*tup)],
                     ['ratio', 'token'])
```

Apply `metrics` to the `compare` series

```
compare.apply(metrics)
```

[image]

There are bunch of ways to do this next part:

Get closest matches to each row of `df1`

```
compare.apply(metrics).unstack().idxmax().unstack(0)
```

[image]

Get closest matches to each row of `df2`

```
compare.apply(metrics).unstack(0).idxmax().unstack(0)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer! But, for large files( ~ lakhs), I get memory error

Comment: I get a `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()`, any ideas?

Comment: I get a TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: Then you have a float value when you are supposed to have strings.  You could gloss over that with some sort of type casting `.astype(str)` but that is probably sweeping under the rug a larger issue.  I'd check why you have floats in whatever column you are attempting to use.

Comment: When I try to unstack, I get `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.