# Pattern matching in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes
I want to match each keyword of Dataframe A with Dataframe B with maximum match of characters.

I am tried by splitting characters but its not giving exact output as required and also very low accuracy.

Also, I have 50 columns in Dataframe B, My time complexity is much more than expected, Is there any way to reduce time complexity by reducing search time?

Sample input :
dataframe 1 = 
[image: This is my second dataframe containing country details]

`dataframe2 - Batu, Balomb, and so on`, containing country words but not exact match.

**I want to search Balomb with Dataframe 1 with the highest matching characters.**

`Expected output should be:`

`If Bolamb found in DF1, it should print word.`

Comment: Please share some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Hi, Added the external details.

Comment: Remove one of your irrelevant tags and add a plain python tag please

Comment: If you are working with pandas, why do you have three Excel-related tags?

Comment: because I created dataframe with this excel file. it was just for reference for people who might be knowing similar way to get rid out of this.,. Although I removed tags as per your suggestion.

Comment: @naitik_chandak: you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092961/fuzzy-lookup-between-2-series-df-columns)

Comment: No thats not useful, I've already checked that. Logic is too different over there and here