# i have multiple columns with the status of the areas,i need to get the status on status column if all the status are completed

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple columns with the status of the areas, I need to get the status on status column if all the status are completed.

[image: Table]

Comment: Areas are 3 or more than that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter all columns with `Area` in columns names by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for `==` and test if all `True`s per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df['Status'] = df.filter(like='Area').eq('Completed').all(axis=1)
```

Or you can seelct all columns without first 2 by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['Status'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].eq('Completed').all(axis=1)
```

Or last 3 columns:

```
df['Status'] = df.iloc[:, -3:].eq('Completed').all(axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks ...i need to know how can i find the extact word,even am getting the similar word

Comment: @Deepweber - Not easy, need [fuzzy match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577332/apply-fuzzy-matching-across-a-dataframe-column-and-save-results-in-a-new-column)