# How to print row number inside apply function after a criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, multi-index

I have a dataframe like as below

```
Company,year                                   
T123 Inc Ltd,1990
T124 PVT ltd,1991
T345 Ltd,1990
T789 Pvt.LTd,2001
ABC Limited,1992
ABCDE Ltd,1994
ABC Ltd,1997
ABFE,1987
Tesla ltd,1995
AMAZON Inc,2001
Apple ltd,2003

compare = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([tf['Company'].astype(str),tf['Company'].astype(str)]).to_series()
compare = compare[compare.index.get_level_values(0) != compare.index.get_level_values(1)]
```

my data looks like below

[image]

I would like to do the below

a) print the index number (i) at the end of comparison of each input key.`for ex: T123 Inc Ltd is compared with ten other strings. So, once it is done and moves to a new/next string/input_key which is T124 PVT ltd, I want the value of i to be incremented by 1 and shown using print function`.

I tried the below

```
def metrics(tup):
print(compare.loc[tup]) # doesn't work. I want the index number 
return list(tup)
```

I don't know how to increment/iterate within `apply` function

I expect my output of print statement to be like as below. Print statement should be executed only after each input key's comparison is over.

```
comparison of 1st input key with 10 strings is done
comparison of 2nd input key with 10 strings is done
```

**update - code**

```
ls = []
ks=[]
for i, k in enumerate(compare, 1):
    ls.append(metrics(k))
    ks.append(k)
    print(f'comparison of {i} input key: {k} with {len(ls)} strings is done')
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(ks),pd.DataFrame(ls)) # error
pd.concat(ks,ls)  # error
```

**metrics**

```
def metrics(tup):
    return pd.Series([fuzz.ratio(*tup),
                      fuzz.token_sort_ratio(*tup),
                      fuzz.token_set_ratio(*tup),
                      fuzz.QRatio(*tup),
                      fuzz.UQRatio(*tup),
                      fuzz.UWRatio(*tup)],
                     ['ratio', 'token','set','qr','uqr','uwr'])
```

Comment: How about `compare.groupby(level=0, sort=False).apply(metrics)`?

Comment: If there are million records, printing group by statement wouldn't crash jupyter notebook?

Comment: So you only want to print the statements, no calculations needs to be done?

Comment: We can store the return output from function in an object. Am I right to thunk tht way? But to know/manage the time, I need to know how many records/keys have been compared. So, I would like to print those smnumbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try enumerating over the unique values in `level 0` index:

```
groups = []
grouper = compare.groupby(level=0, sort=False)

for i, (k, g) in enumerate(grouper, 1):
    # Execute statements here
    groups.append(g.apply(metrics))
    print(f'comparison of {i} input key: {k} with {len(g)} strings is done')

df_out = pd.concat(groups)
```

---

```
comparison of 1 input key: T123 Inc Ltd with 10 strings is done
comparison of 2 input key: T124 PVT ltd with 10 strings is done
...
comparison of 11 input key: Apple ltd with 10 strings is done
```

Comment: Am having some trouble in running the function under for loop. I am expecting my metrics function to return and store the output in dataframe like object. So, you can find my updated code at the bottom of my post. I tried it as two seperate dataframes but that doesn't allow me to concat.

Comment: I don't know whether there is any other better way to store the `input keys` and metrics() output in dataframe`

Comment: @TheGreat What's the return value of `metrics(k)`

Comment: I updated the metrics code at the bottom

Comment: What is the expected value of input argument `tup`?

Comment: the input values are the one from `compare` as shown in screenshot above.

Comment: which I believe is tuples. ex: `(T123 Inc Ltd, T124 PVT ltd)`

Comment: metrics function does the fuzzy matching check and returns the matching 4-5 different matching score

Comment: basically, am trying to do this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577332/apply-fuzzy-matching-across-a-dataframe-column-and-save-results-in-a-new-column

Comment: In that case cant we simply use `compare.apply(metrics)`?

Comment: I want to store the output in dataframe and print the number of rows comparison check done. That's why

Comment: That's this question mainly about. How do we show row number under apply function? If for loop, it is possible to show like you have done. but under apply() function, how can we show that row number?

Comment: Am okay to use for loop as well but having some trouble storing the output. when I print type(ks) and type(ls), it returns list only

Comment: Check the edit.